# Can't apt-get install software on 17.10 on virtualbox - git, ack, and virtualbox-*

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, 17.10

I just setup a new ubuntu 17.10 from osboxes.org and trying to installing the following apps: git, ack, and virtualbox-* to get my bidirectional clipboard to work.

For some reason it doesnt find any packages. The internet does work as I can ping websites.

[image]

Comment: git is indeed in the Ubuntu repos. Check your sources - you must enable (or add) main.

Comment: how to enable the main repo?

Comment: ok i figured it out i unchecked all the boxes on the software and updates window. I thought it was so it doesnt auto download stuff.